# Why is the thyroid gland in the neck?

Tags: human-anatomy, endocrinology, anatomy

The neck seems like an odd place for it. All other neck anatomy must interface between the head and abdomen (trachea, esophagus, circulation, spine etc).

Surprisingly I have not been able to find any explanation for the thyroid’s location.

Comment: Why does the neck "seem a vulnerable place"? If you get a neck injury, the thyroid is the least of your worries. Especially in fish (the thyroid evolved early in vertebrate evolution).

Comment: You’re right. I removed that part.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, I think it is a valid question. Maybe people cannot face that they have no idea. :D

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not the pituitary proximity hypothesis. Simple counter-examples include the adrenal gland (ACTH-cortisol axis), liver (GH-IGF1 axis) and  the gonads (LH/FSH axis).

Comment: Tib is referring to the theory that the the thyroid must be close to the pituitary to respond to TSH stimulation. I have since removed that theory from my original question.

Comment: @Doug I don't think so. We are talking about hormones and to be regulated by hormones you don't have to be close to the source, they travel with the blood. Maybe this way it can answer in 1 min instead of 5 mins, but I don't think that makes a real difference. Maybe you would freeze to death easier if it were be lower, but that is just a guess. I think the real answer is something totally different and we should read more about the evolution of this organ.